# Cucumber Capybara - Find an element based on attribute's content

Tags: cucumber, automated-tests, capybara

My requirement is to check if some particular content (i.e. Id=4540484 in the below example) exists in the onclick attribute on an anchor tag on a page. Can someone help me out please?

```
<a title="Acrobat PDF File" href="#" onclick="openPop('/example/secure/Screen.aspx?Id=4540484&amp;certdocId=2513235)"><img src="New.gif" align="middle" border="0"></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find an element based on the onclick attribute, you will need to use a css (or xpath) selector.

In your case, you want the css-selector:

```
a[onclick*="Id=4540484"]
```

This says to find a link element where the onlclick attribute contains the text "Id=4540484".

You can then use the has_css? method to check if that link is on the page:

```
#Using an ID that exists will return true
page.has_css?('a[onclick*="Id=4540484"]')
#=> true

#Using an ID that does not exist will return false
page.has_css?('a[onclick*="Id=9999999"]')
#=> false
```

Comment: Can we set the value of the attribute `href=` using capybara?

Comment: @Priti, Capybara is meant for driving the browser as a user would. Since a user cannot change the href, Capybara does not have a direct method for doing this. However, depending which driver you are using, there may be a method to inject javascript on the page. For example, if you are using selenium-webdriver, you can use the execute_script method to inject javascript that changes the html attribute.